# Searching a column in a tab delimited array for a specific value

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So i'm trying to use a "column_matches" function to search a txt file with data, which i have stored into an array, for a specific value in a column and then print the line containing that value.

The code I have right now looks something like this:

```
f = open( r'file_directory' )
a = []
for line in f:
    a.append(line)

def  column_matches(line, substring, which_column):  
         for line in a:
             if column_matches(line, '4', 6):
                print (line) 
             else: 
                print('low multiplicity')
```

In this example i'm trying to search the 7th column for the value 4. However, this is currently not printing anything. 
I'm a beginner programmer so this might be very wrong, but would love some feedback as I haven't been able to solve it from other peoples questions. 
Ideally the program should search all lines and print (or save) every line with a specific value in a specific column!

Edit: example input:

K00889.01     0.9990         8.884922995       10.51          0.114124      89.89          1               153    0.8430     0.8210

K01009.01     0.0000          5.09246539        1.17          0.014236      89.14          1               225    0.7510     0.7270

Comment: You are not calling the function `column_matches()` except from within itself. I'm not sure how `column_matches` is supposed to work since the only logic contained within the function relies on its own output.

Comment: What is the output from `print(type(a[0][6]))` after you have finished building the list and before defining the function, and also `print(a[0][6])`? You call the second argument "substring" and then provide an integer so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to match and you haven't provided any example input.

Comment: @roganjosh <class 'str'>, so yeah I guess it should be '4'. print (a[0][6]) doesn't return anything for some reason.

Comment: Ok, it probably isn't printing nothing at all, it's more likely that it's printing the empty string `''`.

Comment: Ah yeah. I added an example input of two lines in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing function doesn't actually have any logic to handle the case that you are trying to search for. Indeed, you have `if column_matches(line, '4', 6):` *inside* the function called `column_matches` so you imply that it has to call itself in order to determine what action to take... that logically just forms an infinite loop (though in your case, nothing actually runs).

This should be similar to your existing approach but should do what you want. It should be relatively resilient to your actual file structure but let me know if it throws errors.

```
data = []
with open('example.txt', 'r') as infile:
    # Will automatically close the file once you're done reading it
    for row in infile:
        data.append(row.replace('\n', '').split())


def column_matches(line, target, column_index):
    try:
       file_data = int(line[column_index])
       if file_data == target:
           return True
       else:
           return False
    except ValueError:
        print('Not a valid number: {}'.format(line[column_index]))
        return False

matching_rows = [] # To store items in data that meet our criteria
for line in data:
    if column_matches(line, 4, 6): 
        matching_rows.append(line) # Function has to return True for this to happen
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! And easy to follow as well. Greatly appreciated!